# Send a PDF attachment using Spring RestTemplate with Basic Auth and Custom headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to send a PDF attachment using PUT sort of like when you attach a document in POSTMAN [POSTMAN EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y5qz.png). The service I'm using will only accept PDF files in the body of the request.

Here is my code:

```
// create new file
FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File("/Users/name/Documents/test.pdf"));
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("file", file);

// adding basic auth
HttpHeaders headers = createHeaders(username, password);
// required custom header
headers.set("X-Async-Scope", timelineEntryId);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, String.class);
```

the problem is the **response** comes with a status code of **415 Unsupported Media Type** and I'm not sure why. is my HttpEntity body in the wrong format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across another solution that helped me a lot! [different solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184470/how-to-frame-resttemplate-for-request-body-of-type-binary-of-postman) here is my final code and solution for my own question.

```
HttpHeaders headers = createHeaders(username, password);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
headers.set("X-Async-Scope", timelineEntryId);

InputStream inputStream = new FileSystemResource(new File(file.getPath())).getInputStream();
byte[] binaryData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(binaryData, headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need set header content type?

```
headers.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
```

If it doesn't help, you should also set header Content-Disposition:

```
headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName)
```

Comment: When I add what you suggested I get the following error: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type [application/pdf], any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

you can try on

```
  String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = "attachment; filename=category_list"  + ".xlsx";
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        categoryServiceImpl.exportToExcelFile(response);
```